# Get this error when transfer to other accounts: `RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction`

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, ganache, smart-contract-wallets

I am using `truffle` and `ganache` for developing smartcontract.

The issue I have is not able call `transfer` method. I got below exception when calling `transfer` inside `sendCoin` method.

```
data: {
    '0xaf712055f3c88fa2d8f7ed037aee02fadb379a99452a7ca95f39b846748a0753': { error: 'revert', program_counter: 738, return: '0x' },
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
      '    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n' +
      '    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n' +
      '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)',
    name: 'RuntimeError'
  },
```

This is the step I did in truffle console:

```
truffle(development)> let ledger = await Ledger.deployed()
truffle(development)> let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
truffle(development)> (await ledger.getBalance(accounts[0])).toNumber()
9990
truffle(development)> await ledger.sendCoin(accounts[1], 10) // this line throws the error above
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Below is the full code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.4;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Ledger {
    struct TransferRequest {
        string title;
        uint256 amount;
        string bsb;
        string accountName;
        string accountNumber;
    }

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    address payable owner;

    event Transfered(address _from, address _to, uint256 amount);

    constructor() payable {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address payable receiver, uint256 amount)
        payable public
        returns (bool sufficient)
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        receiver.transfer(amount);
        emit Transfered(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[addr];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`receiver.transfer(amount);` is not working because balance of your **contract** is less than amount you are trying to send.

First you need to transfer some funds to Ledger contract so it's able to transfer it to another account.

In order to make it to work you need to send some Ether along with method call since sendCoin is payable function.

```
> let ledger = await Ledger.deployed()
> await ledger.sendCoin(accounts[1], 10, {value: 10})
```

Another way how you can do this is to make contract payable and this might give you more clarification on how contract is funded and able to transfer.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.1;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Ledger {
    ...

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Send some funds to contract and after that `sendCoin` to `accounts[1]`

```
> let ledger = await Ledger.deployed()
> ledger.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: ledger.address, value: 10})
> await ledger.sendCoin(accounts[1], 10)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `contract balance`? There are enough balance for the account. but do we need balance for contract?

Comment: You have enough balance on the account but at the point where you are calling `receiver.transfer(amount);` it's sending funds from the contract. So in order to make it work you either need to send some funds along with `sendCoin` call or pre-fund contract with some ether. I added more details in the answer.

Comment: ok I see. I need to use this syntax `{from: accounts[0], to: ledger.address, value: 10}`. Thanks.